# How to effectively use navigation pane

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-studio, navigation-drawer

Apologies for such a basic question, but how can I add a navigation pane to my app (the one that slides in from the left) and how can I make it launch other `Activities` with buttons inside the pane?

Comment: That is called a **Navigation Drawer**. Refer [the official guide](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a Material Design drawer component, like this: http://mikepenz.github.io/MaterialDrawer/

You can start new Activities using [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

If you want to start a new Activity when user clicks a button, you have to create the Intent in the navigation pane's `onItemClick` event handler:

```
@Override
public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem){
  if (position==0){ //user clicked first button in pane
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FancyOtherActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
  }
  if (position==1){ //user clicked second button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GreatAnotherActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
  }

  ... //other buttons
}
```